# Can't give service account permissions to apply an existing role "Error from server (Forbidden) ... attempt to grant extra privileges"

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, role

I am trying to give service account permissions to run `kubectl apply -f somerole.yaml` on an **existing role**.

I created a service account with the following permissions:

```
cat > ~/tmp/Role.yaml <<EOF 
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: default
  name: my-role6
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["roles"]
  verbs: ["replace", "patch", "get", "list", "create"] 
EOF

kubectl create -f ~/tmp/Role.yaml
```

All the background permissions (RoleBinding, context) seems to be good because if I add `pods` in the resources field I can use:
`kubectl get pods --context=myservice6-context`

When I run:

```
kubectl apply -f malrole.yaml --context=$CONTEXT_NAME
```

I received:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "malrole.yaml": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "testrole" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["get"]}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:default:myservice6 5cdb719b-828b-11e8-993e-02420d415928 [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:default system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[PolicyRule{Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" "/apis/*" "/healthz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*""/version"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["roles"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["replace" "patch" "get" "list" "create"]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

More readable version:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): 
    error when creating "malrole.yaml": 
    roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "testrole" is forbidden: 
        attempt to grant extra privileges: 
        [ 
            PolicyRule{
                Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["get"]
            }
        ] 
        user=&{
            system:serviceaccount:default:myservice6 5cdb719b-828b-11e8-993e-02420d415928 
            [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:default system:authenticated] map[]
            } 

        ownerrules=[
            PolicyRule{
                Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], 
                Verbs:["create"]
            } 

            PolicyRule{
                NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" "/apis/*" "/healthz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*""/version"], 
                Verbs:["get"]
            }

            PolicyRule{
                Resources:["roles"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["replace" "patch" "get" "list" "create"]
            }
        ] 


        ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

malrole.yaml (the file I tried to apply):

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: testrole
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

It writes:

> An attemp to grant extra privileges...

Which is taken from this line in the code:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4d9873556201f2766ccf6161f7beac5f76b8fd60/pkg/registry/rbac/validation/rule.go#L52

Not sure why.

According to the documentation:

> ConfirmNoEscalation determines **if the roles for a given user** in a
>   given namespace **encompass** the **provided role**.

But I tried also give myself more permissions (see in the edit) and I still received this error.

**EDIT:**
even when I change the permissions to

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: default
  name: my-role6
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["roles"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

I received:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when applying patch:
{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"Role\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"testrole\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"rules\":[{\"apiGroups\":[\"*\"],\"resources\":[\"pods\"],\"verbs\":[\"list\",\"get\"]}]}\n"}},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["*"],"resources":["pods"],"verbs":["list","get"]}]}
to:
&{0xc420b26840 0xc4202b18f0 default testrole malrole.yaml 0xc4211a8988 0xc42000c008 1638 false}
for: "malrole.yaml": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "testrole" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["get"]}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:default:myservice6 5cdb719b-828b-11e8-993e-02420d415928 [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:default system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[PolicyRule{Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" "/apis/*" "/healthz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" "/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*" "/version"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["roles"], APIGroups:["*"], Verbs:["*"]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

Comment: I would say the service account has no privileges to create roles. Try giving `cluster-admin` role to the service account (myservice6?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@liggitt told me that

> Escalation prevention rejects attempts to create roles containing
>   permissions you do not already possess

Following:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#privilege-escalation-prevention-and-bootstrapping

I found that in order to be able to apply roles I need to have the following permissions:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata: 
  namespace: default
  name: $ROLE_NAME
rules: 
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["roles", "pods"]
  verbs: ["patch", "get", "list"]
```

I am not sure why `pods` should be part of the resource when I am just applying a roles.  But maybe the applying is using some system pod for that.

As it was mentioned in the above link:

> To allow a user to create/update roles:
>
> 1. Grant them a role that allows them to create/update Role or
>      ClusterRole objects, as desired.
> 2. Grant them roles **containing** the
>      **permissions you would want them to be able to set in a Role or
>      ClusterRole.** If they attempt to create or modify a Role or ClusterRole
>      with permissions they themselves have not been granted, the API
>      request will be forbidden.

Comment: The role you are attempting to create contains pod-related permissions, so your creating user needs to have those permissions before they can create a role containing those permissions.